# How to rename values in order in matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Say I have this vector A:

```
A=[2
92
91
91
91
92
9
92
-1
91];
```

I want to write a code to rename the smallest entry as 1, the next smallest entry as 2, and so on. So, I want the output to be:

```
B=[2
5
4
4
4
5
3
5
1
4];
```

How do I do that with a short and efficient code? The code I have been able to write is a "check one by one and rename" kind of code, which is highly inefficient.

```
U=unique(A);
for a=1:size(U,1)
   for b=1:size(A,1)
       if A(b,1)==U(a,1)
          B(b,1)=a;
       end
   end
end
```

Is it possible to write one without using for loops, or one that is otherwise efficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a consequence of [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) sorting the output, your desired array is automatically built by the function and is accessible via the third output:

```
>> A=[2;92;91;91;91;92;9;92;-1;91];
>> [~,~,B] = unique(A)
B =
     2
     5
     4
     4
     4
     5
     3
     5
     1
     4
```

Comment: Damn! I feel embarrassed now.